# Configure injected services with information available in runtime

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to modify injected services with values available from authenticated users.

Using the built-in DI container, I added the required service with Scoped lifetime.

```
services.AddScoped<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();
```

Then registered a custom middleware between authorization and MVC middlewares to modify the repository with user specific information.

```
// Configure authorization middleware

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
     var todoRepository = context.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();
     todoRepository.UserStoreId = context.User.GetUserStoreId();
     await next.Invoke();
 });

 // Configure MVC middleware
```

When the program execute a request, the injected repository within my controller does not presist the saved value.

Am i doing something wrong?
From my understanding, scoped objects are saved within request.

Also, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own service, i.e. `IAuthenticatedUserService`/`AutheticatedUserService`.

Into it, you inject `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
public interface IAuthenticatedUserService
{
    ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
}
```

Then you inject the `IAuthenticatedUserService` into your repository, where you can access the logged-in user.

Of course you could also directly inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your repository and access `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` within it, but since repositories are usually defined in their own assembly, you'd also need to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` package from it which would cause a tight(er) coupling.

But if you don't mind this kind of coupling, just inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your repository, they are supposed to be scoped (=per request) or transient anyways.

P.S. don't forget the Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control mantra: "Don't call us, we call you". You have attempted to call "us" (the repository) to set a value.

Comment: I liked your solution better (IAuthenticatedUserService), as it does not break the Inversion of Control. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Am i doing something wrong? From my understanding, scoped objects are saved within request.

I was able to fix the issue by replacing

`context.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();`

with

```
context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITodoRepository>();
```